# associations in ruby on rails - user creates courses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to create a system which allows for specific users to create a Course record which can be enrolled in by many other users. I've tried a few association techniques such as has_and_belong_to_many, has_many :through and number of other setups but have been unable to get it right.

Basically all that I need is the following:

Course belongs to (is created by) a single User (foreign_id => admin_id).
Course has many enrolled Users (Join Table?).
User has many created Courses.
User can belong to many Courses.
If you have any idea how this would be accomplished I would greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good design is [Canvas LMS](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms).

In short:

- A `User` is just a user.
- A `Course` is just a course.
- An `Enrollment` is an association between a user and a course. An enrollment has a type, which is either a student, a teacher, a TA or an observer. Each type has its own set of permissions.

So, if a user is not in any course, he/she is nothing but a user. A user can at the same time be a teacher in course A and a student in course B. Also, he/she can be both a student and a TA in the same course.

You can add your own enrollment types in your application, such as creator.